# SQL group by return null if one is null

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have orders table that have delete marker column `date_deleted` which value is `null` or `date`

| order_number | item_id | date_deleted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | aaa | null |
| 111 | bbb | null |
| 111 | ccc | 2021-x-x |

I have query to select the fully deleted orders with group by `order_number`

```
SELECT order_number, 
       date_deleted 
FROM orders 
WHERE date_deleted IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY order_number
```

It give me this result

| order_number | date_deleted |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 2021-x-x |

Which indicate that the whole order is deleted but is not.

Is there a way to get `null` when not all of them is null?

Comment: @Akina: ah right. I didn't see that

Comment: @Akina Sorry my bad this is not my actual query (its more complicated) I add it just for the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a case expression to return the latest deleted where *all* records are deleted, and where any are `NULL` the expression will return `NULL`:

```
SELECT order_number, 
        CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(date_deleted) THEN MAX(date_Deleted) END AS date_deleted
FROM orders 
GROUP BY order_number;
```

You may also wish to return the earliest deleted date with `MIN(date_deleted)`, the point is though, if you group by `order_number` you can only return one `date_deleted` and you have to tell the query engine which one you want to return by using some kind of additional logic like `MIN` or `MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

This will only return fully deleted orders.

If you join on itself and check for NULL values(not deleted rows/parts) in the join, than set "if the parts IS NULL" it only included orders where there are no NULL values in the date_deleted part(and thus fully deleted).

This also does not use COUNT or other groupings that could slow the query down so should be fast and readable.

```
SELECT 
    order_number, 
    date_deleted 
FROM orders 
    LEFT JOIN orders openOrderParts ON openOrderParts.order_number = openOrderParts.order_number 
        AND openOrderParts.date_deleted IS NULL
WHERE date_deleted IS NOT NULL AND openOrderParts IS NULL
GROUP BY order_number
```

But you have to remember, it is grouped by order number, do "date_deleted" could contain more than ne value but you are just showing one. you could consider using GROUP_CONCAT there to optionally show all if any.